# Trim is not a function in Protractor

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor, bdd

I am having trouble trimming a result in Protractor to then pass into an array. The field in question contains a string that will form a JSON object.

I pass into the field `element(by.id(fieldName2)).sendKeys('{"Name":"JoeNew"}');`.

This is then pushed into an array with `browser.params.newValues.push(element(by.id(fieldName2)).getAttribute('value'));`. Resulting in `// {"Name":"JoeNew"}` being stored in the array.

I then reload the page and check that the content of that field is indeed what I wanted to store, but because it is JSONified it will come back as:

```
{
    "Name":"JoeNew"
}
```

To compare the two I need to `trim()` this so that it reverts back to `{"Name":"JoeNew"}` for the purposes of comparison.

```
browser.params.updatedValues.push(trimResult(element(by.id(fieldName2)).getAttribute('value')));

function trimResult(toTrim) {
    return toTrim = toTrim.trim();
};
```

Is sadly returning `Failed: toTrim.trim is not a function`. I am however able to perform similar tasks to other field types like `Date.parse(date)` etc without issue.

Can anyone help?

EDIT:

The promises are resolved to compare the two arrays with the following:

```
protractor.promise.all(browser.params.updatedValues).then(function (resolvedValues) {
    console.log(resolvedValues);
    browser.params.updatedValues = resolvedValues;

    expect(browser.params.updatedValues).toEqual(browser.params.newValues);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getAttribute()`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute) function in protractor returns the value in the form of promise, so in order to use `trim()`, you should get the value first and then perform the operation. Here's how -

```
browser.params.updatedValues.push(trimResult(element(by.id(fieldName2)).getAttribute('value')));

function trimResult(toTrim) {
    return toTrim.then(function(val){
        return val.trim();
    });
};
```

---

**EDIT:** However the `push()` function doesn't wait for the promise from `trimResult()` function to be returned. Here's a sample on how you can push the values -

```
element(by.id(fieldName2)).getAttribute('value').then(function(val){
    browser.params.updatedValues.push(val.trim());
});
```

OR

```
trimResult(element(by.id(fieldName2)).getAttribute('value'));

function trimResult(toTrim) {
    toTrim.then(function(val){
        browser.params.updatedValues.push(val.trim());
    });
};
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @girish-sortur. That has removed the Protractor error for the Trim not being allowed, but it doesn't actually trim the result and still logs it in it's expanded form.

Comment: Thanks @DanHodson for pointing that out. That's because push doesn't wait for the function `trimResult()` to return the value which is in the form of promise. Updated answer to include it.

Comment: Hi @girish-sortur Thanks for the edits. I have tried to apply both of these options. The first isn't using the trim function, and the second doesn't actually push in to the array. I should also explain that when I attempt to compare the two arrays I resolve the promises. I have edited my original question as well now to reflect this. Thanks again for taking the time to help :)

Comment: @DanHodson i have added `trim()` function to the value which was missing. Can you check if the `getAttribute()` function is returning a valid value? Also  i don't think you would need to resolve promises when comparing two arrays as the array's are locally stored and it has nothing to do with protractor itself. Thanks

Comment: Hey @girish-sortur I'm finally in business! In the end I did it with the original answer you posted (accepted) and instead of using trim, I went with `JSON.stringify()` and used `.replace()` to remove all the unwanted \\n characters caused by the extra whitespace. Possibly not the most elegant solution, but I now have a passing test! Many thanks!